# How to Add a Component Template to an Existing Composable Index Template

Tags: elasticsearch, templates, indexing

Goals:

- Tweak the default "logs" composable index template that ships with
  Elasticsearch 8.
- Change the number or replicas to 0.
- Use the REST API

I can create a component template without issue:

```
PUT _component_template/no-replicas
{
  "template": {
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "number_of_replicas": "0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, I cannot figure out how to add the component template to the pre-installed "logs" index template, because the [Create or update index template API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-template.html) seems to require that I pass the **entire** index template configuration at once.

I don't want to lose or overwrite any defaults that already exist in the "logs" index template.

Is there a way to do something like this?

```
PUT /_index_template/logs
{
  "ADD_COMPONENTS" : ["no-replicas"]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `logs` index template is composed of the `logs-mappings`, `logs-settings` and `data-streams-mappings` component templates.

So you can simply retrieve `logs-settings`...

```
GET _component_template/logs-settings
```

...add whatever settings you need to it, and store it again:

```
PUT _component_template/logs-settings
{
  "template": {
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "number_of_replicas": 0,            <---- only added this
        "lifecycle": {
          "name": "logs"
        },
        "codec": "best_compression",
        "query": {
          "default_field": [
            "message"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "version": 2,                             <---- modified this
  "_meta": {
    "description": "default settings for the logs index template installed by x-pack",
    "managed": true
  }
}
```

That's it, the next `logs-*` index that's going to be created out of the `logs` index template won't have any replicas.

Comment: Thanks for the strategy @Val! I posted the Python implementation I ended up using as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Python implementation of @Val's answer:

```py
import requests
import sys
import json

# determine where to send requests
elasticsearchApiRoot = sys.argv[1] # for example: http://localhost:9200/"
componentTemplateEndpoint = elasticsearchApiRoot + "_component_template/logs-settings"

# get current settings as json
response = requests.get(componentTemplateEndpoint)
componentTemplateConf = json.loads(response.text)

# set new values
componentTemplateConf["component_templates"][0]["component_template"]["version"] = 2 # overwrites existing value
componentTemplateConf["component_templates"][0]["component_template"]["template"]["settings"]["index"]["number_of_replicas"] = 0 # adds new field

# send update request
newComponentTemplate = componentTemplateConf["component_templates"][0]["component_template"]
response = requests.post(componentTemplateEndpoint, json=newComponentTemplate)

# throw error for anything except 200 (OK)
if response.status_code == 200:
    sys.exit(0)
else:
    sys.exit(response.status_code)
```